# How to use jsonapi-vuex [es6 module export] with Jest?

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I'm trying to make use of the `jsonapi-vuex` npm package. I import it within my code like so:
`import { jsonapiModule } from "jsonapi-vuex";`

Jest however stumbles over this package. This package uses es6 modules. The `index.js` for that node module looks like this:

```
export { jsonapiModule, utils } from './src/jsonapi-vuex'
```

Jest fails on this even though `babel-jest` is installed with the following error:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token
/node_modules/jsonapi-vuex/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export { jsonapiModule, utils } from './src/jsonapi-vuex'
                                                                                             ^^^^^^
```

I've tried various things:

1. Tried adding to jest config so that just shouldn't ignore this library when transpiling:

```
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!jsonapi-vuex)"
  ],
```

2. Tried the `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` plugin

As far as I can tell, `babel-jest` makes use of `.babelrc`. I have this configured with the `@babel/preset-env` preset, which is supposed to handle es6 modules... so I really don't understand why it is failing. Here's the `.babelrc`

```
{
"presets": [
  [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    {
      "modules": "commonjs",
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }
  ]
]}
```

Comment: Have you solved your issue? I'm having the same here

Comment: No. I have not. @CamilleHuot